# Somar e subtrair segundo um criterio em outra coluna

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho um dataframe f0519_grouped como o da imagem. "Identificação Única" é o código que identifica o funcionário dos demais; "Código Rubrica" identifica o pagamento; tenho também o nome do funcionário e "Valor" identifica o valor, que pode somar ou descontar. Sempre que o Código Rubrica for igual a 352, há um desconto. Se for qualquer outro valor, deve ser somado.
No exemplo da figura, eu preciso somar os códigos que não são 352, ou seja 1058,  1080 ou 1387 e subtrair quando o código da rubrica for igual a 352. E o resultado eu devo comparar se é superior a 39000.
No caso, eu devo fazer 3546222 + 1564.47 + 11820.84 - 9554.11 = 39293.32, que é o resultado que espero obter. E, em seguida, comparar se é maior que 39000.
Estou usando Pandas e o código abaixo, mas não sei por que ele não soma e nem desconta de acordo com as rubricas. Segue o codigo. Grato.

```
f0519_grouped['Valor']=(f0519_grouped['Valor'] - (f0519_grouped['Valor'].where(f0519_grouped['Código Rubrica']==352)).fillna(0))
f0519_grouped[f0519_grouped["Valor"]>39000]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu te entendi, tu pode fazer isso somando toda a coluna `Valor` e subtrair pelo dobro da soma onde `Código Rubrica` é igual a 352.

```
sub352 = f0519_grouped.loc[f0519_grouped['Código Rubrica'] == 352, 'Valor'].sum()

f0519_grouped['Valor'].sum() - (sub352 * 2) > 39000
#saida:
True
```

Outra forma seria criar um array de seleção boleano e somar a coluna `Valor`:

```
mask = df['Código Rubrica'] == 352
f0519_grouped.loc[~mask, 'Valor'].sum() - f0519_grouped.loc[mask, 'Valor'].sum() > 39000
#saida:
True
```

### Edit

Como vai ser necessário fazer a verificação para cada **Identificação Única** no DF, eu converteria para negativo o número na coluna **Valor** onde a rubrica é igual a 352, após isso, com `groupby` repetiria a soma dos valores.

```
df2 = df.copy()

mask = df2['Código Rubrica'] == 352
df2.loc[mask, 'Valor'] = df2.loc[mask, 'Valor'].abs().mul(-1)

df2 = df2.groupby('Identificação Única')['Valor'].sum().reset_index()
df2['Maior que 39000'] = df2['Valor'] > 39000
```

Comment: Acho que não vai dar certo, pois não se trata apenas de um funcionário, e sim de vários. Ou seja, abaixo, do funcionário de Identificação Única = 364, eu tenho outro de Identificação Única 365, depois, 366 e por aí vai(as matriculas de repetem porque são vários tipos de pagamento que um mesmo funcionário recebe, identificadas pelo campo "Código Rubrica).

Comment: @rogerroger Editei minha resposta

Comment: Perfeito! Era disso mesmo que eu precisava. Muito obrigado!